# what is the correct syntax to query database from ms access jdbcodbc in java

Tags: java, ms-access

I have this error when querying the ms access database using java eclipse.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function txtIcNo.getText' in expression.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at GetDataFromDB.retrieveDB(GetDataFromDB.java:103)
    at GetDataFromDB.actionPerformed(GetDataFromDB.java:79)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)"
```

My code is as below

```
 public void retrieveDB() throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException{
    //load JDBC Driver
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:PatientDB");
    String query = "SELECT * FROM PatientDB WHERE IC_No = txtIcNo.getText()";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    con.commit();
    while(rs.next()){
    if("txtIcNo.getText()"!=null){

    txtIcNo.setText(rs.getObject(1).toString());    
    txtName.setText(rs.getObject(2).toString());
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Bye bye");
    }
    }
    con.close();
    }
```

Comment: Is PatientDB a table?  Also, Shouldn't you append the txtIcNo.getText() to your String?  If not, where is the object txtIcNo?  Let me know if I am getting your question wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a learning exercise then try something like

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM PatientDB WHERE IC_No = '" + txtIcNo.getText() + "'";
```

If this is for production code then do **not** use the above. Instead, do some Web searches on "SQL injection" attacks, then learn about "Parameterized queries" and use those.